# More photoshop layer tag colors?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Whenever I use larger documents with multiple layers I always run into the problem of not having enough colors to label my layers.

Is there a way to get more colors for these labels? I've searched high and low for a way or maybe a plugin but it appears there aren't any. Am I the only one with this problem? Or is there a more efficient way to label layers?

I'm currently using Photoshop CC btw. Thanks!

Comment: Both other 'usual' Creative Suite programs -- Illustrator and InDesign -- have an "Other.." selection in color dropdown for the Layer properties. Seems like yet another oversight.

Comment: Did previous versions ever have the "Other.." selection?

Comment: And five years later nothing has changed. I use groups for my layers and would really appreciate Adobe to add more colours or give us option to create our own colour coding system.

Comment: The last feature request i made to Adobe took 15 years to do. Even critical clients are looking at 5 years. You are insignificant in adobes eyes.

Comment: It is so frustrating that we are limited to 7/8 colors. As someone who works on huge files with a ton of layers. Specific and more robust custom color coding would be really helpful for quick scrolling between layers and groups.

Comment: I think it be great actually to define additional colors away from the six that are offered, I have a project that contain 2-3 items in ea. layer for a total of 60 layers. As an artist I feel a bit limited here and having used PS for 25 years, but less and less so until a project I agreed to do out Adobe 3D Painter.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an exact solution to your issue, but you could try grouping your layers, if you haven't already.  You can also convert layers used in the creation of a single element (in this example, text and a shape to make a button) to `Smart Objects`.  Both of these methods will clean up your `Layers Panel` and subsequently reduce the number of different colors needed to keep everything organized.

[image] to [image]

You also don't need every layer in the document to be a different color.  You can reuse the same colors, just make sure that you don't put two of the same color touching each other and you should be able to keep everything organized.

[image]

Naming goes a ***very*** long way too.  I've been using PS for 15+ years and I don't think I've ever colored a layer.  I use groups, `Smart Objects`, and name everything meticulously.

Comment: To group layers, select the ones you want grouped and hold down SHIFT while clicking the little folder icon.  To create a smart object, select your layers, and CTRL [or right] click, then choose Convert to Smart Object