# Photoshop - With Layer 'A' clicked in the Layers window, how do I make a selection for Layer 'B' from the canvas?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

[image]

Normally I would do these steps to achieve the image above:

1. Click 'A' from the Layers window.
2. Find 'B' from the Layers window, but not click it.
3. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+Click 'B' from the Layers window to make a selection of ‘B’.

But once you accumulate 100+ layers, 2) & 3) becomes inconvenient because you have to relocate 'A' and click in the Layers window.

Is there a way to perform 3) straight from the Canvas with 'A' clicked in the Layers window?

Comment: The best I could come up with: record a script using Scripting Listener where I make that selection from the active layer. Then assign a shortcut for the script. Then the workflow would be this: **1.** select layer B in the canvas with `Cmd+Alt+Right-click`, **2.** run the script, **3.** select layer A in the canvas with `Cmd+Alt+Right-click`. And the non script version of this is to do step 2 from a PS Action or by manually doing it in the Layers panel.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't. But you can optimise your workflow:

- Keep your files organised: Name your layers properly, [group them](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/photoshop-reduce-chaos-layer-groups.html). Try [layer tag colours](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/43139/more-photoshop-layer-tag-colors). If you're working with a lot of layers "Rectangle 1" and "Layer 22" are meaningless.
- Do the selection first (<kbd>RMB</kbd> on canvas on top of **B**, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to make the selection  [<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> on Windows]) then switch to **A** layer by <kbd>RMB</kbd> on canvas on top of the **A** area and find **A** in the drop-down menu.

Comment: Yeah good point, I usually keep my layers heavily organized but just wished this was possible for the sake of convenience.

Comment: What's that in Windowsese, please?

Comment: @Vincent CMD on OSX = CTRL on Windows, always. Ok, I'll edit...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have no problem with Cmd or Option, but these symbols always throw me for a loop 

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can but I have some suggestions:

### Save/load selection

You can save an active selection as a channel with *Select > Save Selection*. You can then either keep the Channels panel open and Cmd + left-click the channel or you can load the selection using *Select > Load Selection*.

### Change your workflow

Of course I haven't seen what you work with, but it seems a bit strange that you need to reuse the same selection over and over. Why not just make a group with the selection as mask, place the different fills inside the group and toggle them as needed?

### Switch to Illustrator

If you are making lots of similar elements it might be easier to do in a vector based application like Illustrator (or even InDesign). Then you can spread out your buttons (or whatever) in X/Y instead of stacking them in Z. Asset export can be automatized.